# How to assign CustomFlowLayout to CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have created a custom of **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** for my **UICollectionViewController**, but I'm unclear on how to actually assign it. In Interface Builder, I can set the layout to "custom", but it only accepts a **UICollectionViewLayout**.

I found this [tutorial](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/create-3-column-grid-view-with-uicollectionview/), and it suggests that I assign it programmatically using this line of code:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[CustomImageFlowLayout alloc] init];
```

I have tried the swift version of this code but my class doesn't seem to recognize it. Here is my current code in my UICollectionViewFlowLayout class:

```
class CustomImageFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLayout()
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        minimumLineSpacing = 1
        scrollDirection = .vertical
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        set {
        }
        get {
            let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3

            let itemWidth = (self.collectionView!.frame.width) - (numberOfColumns - 1) / numberOfColumns
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I assign this flow layout to my collection view controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post where you're trying to set the layout on your collection view? This is just the definition of your layout class.

Comment: This is the line of code that it is suggested I use to assign the layout to the collection view: self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[CustomImageFlowLayout alloc] init];  However, I can't successfully implement this in the CustomImageFlowLayout class or the CollectionViewController class as I get an "expected declaration" error. The tutorial is unclear on where exactly I should call this and it doesn't seem to work anywhere.

Comment: It looks like you can only set it when you're initializing the view controller or the collection view -- see `UICollectionView.init(frame:, collectionViewLayout:)` and `UICollectionViewController.init(collectionViewLayout:)`